# Align horizontally form containing select

Tags: html, css

``

```
<div class="container">
<form class="horizontal" action="https://homirent.cloudbeds.com/#/" method="get">
<p class="p1"> City: <select name="city">
<option value="all">All Cities</option>
<option>Cancún</option>
<option>Ciudad De México</option>
<option>Santiago De Querétaro</option>
</select>
Check-In:
<input type="text" name="check_in" placeholder="01/01/2023"/>
Check-Out:
<input type="text" name="check_out" placeholder="02/01/2023"/>
  <input type="submit" /> </p>
</form>
</div>
```

``
We would like to be able to align these forms that contain checkboxes horizontally like the following example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOgBi.png)

Tried using `display: inline-block` on selects instead of `float: left` however not all elements lined up as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap every form element in another class and then use `display: inline-block`

Check this out https://jsfiddle.net/rx4hvn/3Ldp90e6/

```
  <div class="form-control">
    <label>City</label>
    <select name="city">
      <option value="all">All Cities</option>
      <option>Cancún</option>
      <option>Ciudad De México</option>
      <option>Santiago De Querétaro</option>
    </select>
  </div>

.form-control {
  display: inline-block;
}
```